# Ganache Invalid Remainer error

Tags: solidity, web3.py, ganache

I am currently using ganache, i am getting the following error when i execute `w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)`

Transaction Object:

```
{'from': '0xcB39af14219Cb0423d5Add2e796e25F961f4d51c', 'chainId': 1337, 'maxFeePerGas': 39590000000, 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 2000000000, 'nonce': 5, 'value': 4000000000000000000, 'gas': 68612, 'to': '0x5fD636c6fD263Aa4D70CDE4f1f97D3959d7BC49A', 'data': '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'}
```

ERROR:

```
  File "D:\xyz\.\app\infrastructure\execute_contract.py", line 32, in runNow
    tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
  File "D:\xyz\env\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 831, in send_raw_transaction
    return self._send_raw_transaction(transaction)
  File "D:\xyz\env\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "D:\xyz\env\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "D:\xyz\env\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'invalid remainder', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: invalid remainder\n    at Object.decode (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\rlp\\src\\index.ts:75:11)\n    at StateManager.queueRawTransaction (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\statemanager.js:298:29)\n    at GethApiDouble.eth_sendRawTransaction (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\geth_api_double.js:338:14)\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\geth_api_double.js:109:10)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\subproviders\\filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\subproviders\\subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:123:3)\n  
  at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:107:12)', 'name': 'Error'}}
```

Before executing that, i am able to estimate gas, get nonce.

All the steps works fine except the sending of transaction. Also i am unable to understand what is the error.